# how to include multiple input forms in one page in Flask?

Tags: flask

a while ago I made a simple web app with flask that had only 1 input form. I'm now working on another app that will have 8 input forms and I'm unable to figure out how to get it to work with more than one input form. It seems to be that there can only be one url endpoint and each function needs to have the same name as the endpoint. I tried wrighting one function that takes in all 8 inputs but each form is named and it was only able collect 1 form at a time. To put in simple terms, I have an app with 8 user input forms and I'm trying to collect these inputs and store them in a MySQL database.

````
from flask import Flask, request, jsonify, render_template
import mysql.connector
from getpass import getpass
from mysql.connector import connect
password = input('Enter password: ')
connection = connect(host='localhost', user='root', password=password, database='leads')
cursor = connection.cursor()
connection2 = connect(host='localhost', user='root', password=password, database='fox_data_consulting')
cursor2 = connection2.cursor()

app = Flask(__name__)
#name, customer, domain = processUserInput(name, customer, domain)

@app.route('/')
def home():
    return render_template('index.html')

#try using another function with the same name
@app.route('/store', methods=['POST'])
def store(): #name would be more practical but it's unable to work unless it matches the route
    name = request.form['name'].lower()
    cursor.execute('''INSERT INTO test (col1) VALUES ('{}');'''.format(name))
    connection.commit()
    '''
    #werkzeug.exceptions.BadRequestKeyError: 400 Bad Request: The browser (or proxy) sent a request that this server could not understand. KeyError: 'landingPage'
    landingPage = request.form['landingPage'].lower()
    cursor.execute("INSERT INTO test (col2) VALUES ('{}');".format(landingPage))
    connection.commit()'''
    return name

#second function under the same route
'''def landingPage():
    #werkzeug.exceptions.BadRequestKeyError: 400 Bad Request: The browser (or proxy) sent a request that this server could not understand.KeyError: 'name'
    landingPage = request.form['landingPage']
    cursor.execute("INSERT INTO test (col2) VALUES ('{}');".format(landingPage))
    connection.commit()
    return landingPage'''

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app.run(debug=True, threaded=True)```

The docstrings is code that I've tried but didn't work, Thank you in advance.
````

Answer (score 0):

It turns out I could have multiple routes in the app, this has been resolved